# Run SSH Script from remote machine locally

Tags: encryption, ssh, raspberry-pi, synology

I am searching for a way to run a .sh Script located on MachineB on MachineA.  So I don't want to run the script remotely. I want to run the script locally (the script is located on a remote machine).

I have tested this command

```
ssh pi@192.168.1.2 "/usr/local/bin/nas/script1.sh"
```

But with this the command get executed remotely.

Background info: MachineA is my Synology-NAS; MachineB is my RaspberryPI.

All my folders on the NAS are encrypted. If the NAS reboots, all folders are unmounted. I want to automate the mounting process, but don't want to share the keys on a USB-Media for security reasons. For that I have a script with the keys for all folders on my PI in an encrypted folder. 
The PI is online 24/7. For the scenario of theft. The Raspberry will a) not be stolen, b) will power-off and the encrypted folder will be unmounted. So, the keys are safe.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a starting point, try:

```
/bin/bash <<end
`ssh pi@192.168.1.2 "cat /usr/local/bin/nas/script1.sh"`
end
```

Comment: This seems to be working.
Now I've got an permission error. But the Script was executed locally
`/bin/bash: line 7: /usr/syno/sbin/synoshare: Permission denied`

Thank you!